# Error Magento search module

Tags: php, magento

I have get this error after write any text in searching string in Magento frontend 1.9.0.1

> mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening
>   required
>   '/var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocsapp/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/controllers/ResultController.php'
>   (include_path='/var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/app/code/local:/var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/app/code/community:/var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/app/code/core:/var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/lib:.:')
>   in
>   /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/app/code/local/Smartwave/Ajaxcatalog/controllers/CatalogSearch/ResultController.php
>   on line 5, referer: http ://site.com/search/

Have anybody know about it? 
Also page /search have 404 error
but advanced search working good

Answer (score 0):

`/site.com/httpdocsapp/code/` have to be `/site.com/httpdocs/app/code/`

Check `/var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/app/code/local/Smartwave/Ajaxcatalog/controllers/CatalogSearch/ResultController.php` on line 5 to know where is defined the path and add the slash

Comment: Thanks Error was in \app\code\local\Smartwave\Ajaxcatalog\controllers\CatalogSearch\ResultController.php